# Triggering a LED and interrupting it quickly (with a PIR sensor). What do I need for this?

Tags: led, switches, timer, pulse, pir

I'm an artist working on a interactive installation. I'm a beginner in electronics and I'm feeling a little bit lost here, can you help me?

I have a 5v circuit with a PIR sensor activating a LED and a sound module. The minimum output from the PIR sensor is HIGH for about 3 seconds and then LOW for another 3 seconds. I need to flash the LED quickly, not stay on HIGH for 3 seconds.

The LED is just to demonstrate what I am trying to do. This is actually to trigger the sound module that I am using, which is triggered only by a short pulse. If it stays HIGH for 3 seconds it doesn't trigger it (just changes the volume). Basically, I'm trying to use the PIR sensor as a momentary button.

I know I could use an Arduino for this, but I need very cheap pieces for this project (cheaper than Arduino) as I will have many copies of the same circuit. What do I need for this? A timer or switch module, capacitors?

I really appreciate any help from the community!! Thanks!

Comment: You could use a cheap microcontroller. There are 6 pin 8 bit microcontrollers under $1. That would require skills in programming it though...

Comment: How quick is quick? Are we talking human perception quick? (That would be ages in electronics ) maybe you can use a high pass filter.

Comment: Quick as the push of a button...probably anything less than 30ms will work.

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't involve a microcontroller? It seems to be such a simple thing..it's only necessary to stop the energy flow just after the LED has been activated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a 555 oscillator?
It can be triggered by a rising edge and the duration of les flash is configurable by a resistor and a capacitor.

I don't know if is the cheapest solution but is the most classical approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this solution soon and let you know if I managed to do it.

Comment: I can confirm this method works, although I found out another problem (the LED works OK, but the sound module button connects to ground...but I will sort this out later). Thanks!